# How to fix label clipping in Mapbox Studio

Tags: tiles, mapbox

I have labels that are being cut off when rendered in Mapbox Studio. As I understand it there is a 256x256 tile that gets rendered and if the label text "bleeds" into another tile it may get cut off. Research led me to a 'buffer-size:' thing but that isn't making any difference whether I set it to 0, 512, or 60000.

[image: Label-clipping]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buffers are now handled in the source project, not in the style project (in TileMill, one project controlled both data source and style; in MapBox Studio, they are now two different projects).

So, assuming you have access to the source file, click on the label layer, and under the configure tab increase **Buffer Size** to a number half the width of your widest label (or just estimate).

[image]

See the [source quickstart](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/source-quickstart/), [source manual](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/source-manual/), and [styling labels doc](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/styling-labels/).

**Edit**
If large labels are still an issue even with increased buffer size, it's possible to shrink text size for labels with high letter counts using regex expressions in the selectors.  Something like

@text-size: 22;

```
#label-layer{
    text-name: [name];
    text-size: @text-size;
    [name=~'^.{10,}$'] {
        text-size: @text-size * 0.8;
    }
    [name=~'^.{14,}$'] {
        text-size: @text-size * 0.6;
    }
}
```

See [this answer to another question on conditional labeling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131443/cartocss-expression-for-shield-name).